# Is it okay to whistle while at the office?

Tags: professionalism, united-states, noise

I enjoy whistling from time to time, and like to think that I'm pretty good at it; i.e., it's not displeasing to listen to, unless you just don't like whistling. And, if need be, I can whistle at a pretty low volume - somewhere between that of a whisper and a casual conversation.

Being in a cubicle setting office, would it be acceptable to occasionally whistle? Perhaps, while walking down the hall, or, in the break room when making a cup of coffee? How about while in my cubicle?

Also, would this kind of "chipper" attitude be ill-received over time?

Comment: It creates distractions, which is very counterproductive for knowledge workers.

Comment: If you can convince your colleagues that you are a were-bird, maybe they will understand.

Comment: Friendly and from a person that has worked in several offices: Please, just don't.

Comment: A question from the other side - [How To Deal With a Whistler](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10779/how-to-deal-with-a-whistler)

Comment: VTC Primarily Opinion Based for sure.  Whistling at work in an office environment, under the assumption that everyone will like it is naive.  Its obnoxious as @Kat points out in their answer.

Comment: This is a ridiculous question. Just as well I could say, "I enjoy listening to heavy metal from time to time, and like to think that it's pretty good; it's not displeasing to listen to, unless you just don't like heavy metal." Would it be a question whether to play heavy metal at work loudly?

Comment: @idmean Hmm.. I think that the specific musical genre of heavy metal has a much more narrow audience of whom is at least tolerant of that music, than those tolerant to casually whistled, obscure melodies. Of course, this is pure speculation. I'm always curious though.. When providing an argument, why do so many people feel the need to argue the extreme? I mention whistling, you immediately think of heavy metal.. great job mate.

Comment: @Charles Because some people like to use rhetoric figures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole

Comment: @MisterPositive I never mentioned that anyone would like it. I simply said that the quality of my whistling isn't displeasing in and of itself. Perhaps somewhat analogous to a beginning violinist vs. an seasoned amateur.

Comment: @idmean Yes, and if you read the description on that page, it states, *As a figure of speech, it is usually not meant to be taken literally*. You, however, are intending to convey your statement quite literally (at least, from I can tell thus far), and so, this is not a hyperbole. Your argument *is* though considered to be a form of "Reductio ad absurdum".

Comment: @Charles I VTC'ed as opinion based as the matter of whilsting depends on the opinion of your colleages. Go ask them, there is no definitve rule, it all depends on who you work with and your envrioment. Random people on the internet will not know your surroudings. Don't forget, you say you're good, but you also need to check your colleages think your good and enjoyable to listen to

Comment: @Draken I see your point. This line of distinction seems rather sensitive though, since if there was a definitive "rule", then that would be listed as a company policy, of which, from what I currently understand, would also be granted a hold, since that would then pertain to company-specific policy. And, side note -- respectfully speaking, I've been studying & performing music for more than half my life. I can tell if I'm in tune or not, and, have been randomly complimented on my whistling multiple times over the span of years. This is why I'm casual and confident when making those statements.

Comment: @Charles You could be the greatest whilster in the world, doesn't mean I would want to hear you whilst working. Each person is different, some may enjoy your tunes and find it fun, others won't. That's why you need to speak to your colleages.

Comment: @Draken I understand and agree with you completely :) Do you suggest that I remove my edit then, that addresses the hold? I only wrote that because that's how I interpreted the hold description. I'm fairly new to Workplace.SE, so I'm still learning the ropes.

Comment: Hi Charles, You already got good answers. And I don't think any edit will help you improve your question, so probably is better just move on. Unless you question is how I can make my coworker let me whistle on the office. In this case the consensus is any noise in the workplace is distracting and people doesn't like that. And my guess is just the mention of someone whisper bring bad memories from some annoying coworker and now you get the residual anger. In my case I can easily get upset when my desk neighbor finger tap on the table.

Comment: I think it's fine to whistle in the office if you're willing to risk your neighbor leaping the cubicle wall and strangling you.

Comment: There should be a jar that you put $1 into if you whistle.

Comment: There is a disorder called "misophonia" which causes its sufferers to be *extremely* disturbed by sounds such as whistling.  You should be sensitive to that.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Short answer:** In general, no it's not appropriate in an office setting.

While you may feel that the sound of your whistling is quiet and not displeasing, it is by nature a piercing sound that can travel a lot further than you think it will.  It will almost certainly annoy your co-workers if done in your cubicle.

You might get away with the occasional tune in the toilet or kitchen away from where people are trying to concentrate, or if you had your own office with a door, but otherwise it is not a good idea in an open office layout.

Comment: Additionally as an alternative you can approximate whistling by shaping your breaths as you breathe normally, which is no louder than a whisper. Still not at your desk - just in common areas. Works for me.

Comment: Higher frequency waves (like sound waves as a result of whistling) dissipate faster, and thus travel less distance, which makes whistling no more "piercing" than say regular speech.

Answer (score 21):

**Making noise that stands out from the ambient noise level is obnoxious.** If you work in a mall, then no one will care. If you work in a library, then you will aggravate people around you. The break room at a typical office is almost certainly fine; people tend to chat and laugh there anyway. Whether it's okay in other areas (such as at your desk or in a hallway) solely depends on if it stands out from the regular noise level. A good way to judge is to see if people look your way when you start to whistle. If they do, you're exceeding the normal noise level/tones, and you should stop.

The happy attitude shouldn't be an issue. If it is, you might want to start looking for a new place to work.

Comment: I'd disagree that a mall or break room is fine. Whistling can stand out and be really irritating even if it isn't strictly louder than the ambient noise. A common human response is to suffer in silence and make a big deal out of it when it becomes intolerable, so I wouldn't take anyone else's response or lack of one to be a definite sign of whether it's appropriate (not to mention that you probably can't see everyone who can hear it or notice them briefly looking around).

Comment: There is a time a place for everything, if you're keen to whistle go to the park and whistle not at the work place/mall/train/ where there a lot of people...